# find this limit $\lim_{x+\rightarrow 0}e^{-1/x}/x^2$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I want to find this limit

$$\lim_{x_+\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}$$

I know that exponential convergence rate is faster, but how to find the limit mathematically?

thanks.

Comment: consider the cases $x->0-0,x->0+0$

Comment: The right limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{0}$, so it $\infty$. As for the left limit, exponential defeats the power, so the limit is $0$.

Comment: yes this is true

Comment: What does $x+\to 0$ mean?

Comment: it means $x$ tends to 0 from the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1/x^{2}}{e^{1/x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{2/x}{e^{1/x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{-2}{e^{1/x}}=0$ after two applications of L'Hospital.